# jQuery - Pass a variable through a button value

Tags: jquery, html, button

I'm trying to create a form on my application that allows a user to input a name and address. Once the user inputs the information, I need to validate and add it an array to be submitted to the php function. Before it's submitted, I want to allow the user to delete and edit what they've submitted.

Right now I can add the data to the array but I'm having a hard time delete an element in an array. How can assign the button value the index value of the array. I know that `$('#Delete').val(i);` is being reassigned with each iteration of the for loop but I'm not sure what else to do.

Also, I'm definitely still a novice JavaScript. If you see a better way to do this, which there most likely is, please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var ItemArray = [];//Initialize array
  
  $("button").click(function() {
  
    $("#results").empty();//Clear results div
    
    //Add form data to array
    ItemArray.push({
      FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
      LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    });

  //iterate through array to display array values
    for (i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {


      $("#results").append(ItemArray[i]['FirstName'] + " " + ItemArray[i]['LastName'] + " <br>");//Display  First and Last Name


      $("#results").append('<button id="Delete" value="">Delete</button><br>');//add delete button

      $('#Delete').val(i);//set delete button value

    }


  });

  //Delete
  $("#results").on("click", "#Delete", function() {

  //Delete selected index from array
    ItemArray.splice($('#Delete').val(), 1);
    
  //clear div
    $("#results").empty;
    
  //iterate through array to display array values
    for (i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {


      $("#results").append(ItemArray[i]['FirstName'] + " " + ItemArray[i]['LastName'] + " <br>");//Display  First and Last Name


      $("#results").append('<button id="Delete" value="">Delete</button><br>');//add delete button

      $('#Delete').val(i);//set delete button value

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  First name:
  <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
  <br> Last name:
  <input id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse">
  <br>
</form>

<button>Submit</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: didn't quite get what you want to do? did you mean the delete button can only delete the last record user submit?

Comment: first thing change `$("#results").append('<button id="Delete"` to `$("#results").append('<button class="Delete"` coz id should be unique

Comment: ... And since you're generating the button directly as html, why not just set it to `'<button value="' + i + '">Delete</button><br>'`, instead of generating it on one line, then setting the value on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wrap HTML to be appended in `div` element so that it will be easier to find/remove `div` element.

There is no point to `iterate` `ItemArray` array on every `add/remove` operation.

Use `.delete` instead of `#delete`(id) as you should no have multiple elements having same value for id attributes.

Use `data-index` attribute to get the `index` of the current clicked element.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ItemArray = [];
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    ItemArray.push({
      FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
      LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    });
    $("#results").append('<div>' + $('#FirstName').val() + " " + $('#LastName').val() + " " + '<br><button class="delete" data-index="' + (ItemArray.length - 1) + '">Delete</button><br></div>');
  });
  $("#results").on("click", ".delete", function() {
    ItemArray.splice($(this).data('index'), 1);
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  First name:
  <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
  <br>Last name:
  <input id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse">
  <br>
</form>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
<hr/>
<div id="results"></div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/nfkztLsa/)

Answer (score 0):

how about putting a wrapper for each name&button combo? you don't have to maintain an array in JS, you can just store all the patterns in DOM and read from it when needed. like this:

```
 $('#submit').on('click',function(){
     var record = "<div class='record'>" +
                       "<span class='name'>....</span><button class='delete'>delete</div>" + 
                  "</div>";

    $('#result').append(record);


 })//adding name&button

 $('.delete').on('click',function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.closest('.record').remove();
 })// delete a record.


function getArray(){

  var ItemArray;
  $.each($('.record'),function(index,record){
      ItemArray.push(.....)


   })
  return ItemArray;
}//read from DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a new approach, try like this.I have used `Object` instead of `Arrays`

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var itemsObj;

    $("button").click(function() {
      $("#results").empty();
      itemsObj = {
        FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
        LastName: $('#LastName').val()
      };
      for (var property in itemsObj) {
        $("#" + property).after('<a href="#" class="delete" id="' + property + '" value="">Delete ' + itemsObj[property] + '</a><br>'); //add delete button
      }
    });

    $("#frm").on('click', '.delete', function() {
      var idEle = this.id;
      $('#' + idEle).val('');
      $(this).remove();
      delete itemsObj[idEle];
      console.log(itemsObj);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id='frm'>
  First name:
  <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
  <br>Last name:
  <input id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse">
  <br>
</form>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping you logic intact I have updated your code kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/r4qufcfg/

**Modified jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var ItemArray = [];//Initialize array

  $("button").click(function() {

    $("#results").empty();//Clear results div

    //Add form data to array
    ItemArray.push({
      FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
      LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
    });

        //iterate through array to display array values
    for (var i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {


      $("#results").append(ItemArray[i]['FirstName'] + " " + ItemArray[i]['LastName'] + " <br>");//Display  First and Last Name


      $("#results").append('<button class="Delete" value="'+i+'">Delete</button><br>');//add delete button

    }


  });

  //Delete
  $("#results").on("click", ".Delete", function() {

        //Delete selected index from array
    ItemArray.splice($(this).val(), 1);

        //clear div
    $("#results").empty();

        //iterate through array to display array values
    for (i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {


      $("#results").append(ItemArray[i]['FirstName'] + " " + ItemArray[i]['LastName'] + " <br>");//Display  First and Last Name

                 $("#results").append('<button class="Delete" value="'+i+'">Delete</button><br>');//add delete button


    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to deviate much from your original code you can modify your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var ItemArray = []; //Initialize array

  $("button").click(function() {

  $("#results").empty(); //Clear results div

  //changed it a little bit, refactor according to your
 //requirements.
//Add form data to array, use splice for bulk pushing
  ItemArray.splice(0, 0, {
    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName').val()
  }, {
    Address: $('#Address').val(),
    Country: $('#Country').val()
  }, {
    Type: $('#Type').val()
  });

  //iterate through array to display array values
 //Homework: Wrap this block in a function
 /****************/
 for (i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {

   var keysArray = Object.keys(ItemArray[i]);
   var valueToAppend = "";
   for (var m = 0; m < keysArray.length; m++) {
     valueToAppend += ItemArray[i][keysArray[m]] + " ";
    //Homework(optional): Add the space between " " based 
    //on codition of not last entry in keysArray or there 
    //is more than single item in keysArray. 
    //Hint: use ternary operator
   }
  /**********************/

   $("#results").append(valueToAppend + " <br>"); 

  //id must be unique so use class instead of id in button 
  //set value of button while appending it 
  $("#results").append('<button class="Delete" value="' + i + '">Delete</button><br>'); //add delete button
}
});

//Delete
$("#results").on("click", ".Delete", function() {

  //Delete selected index from array
  //use 'this' not $('.Delete'), using $('.Delete') will
 //target the first of its kind in the DOM every time
 ItemArray.splice($(this).val(), 1);
 console.log(ItemArray);

 //Tip: Don't Redraw i.e. empty and refill $('#result') on every
 //delete. Just delete the desired node from DOM using code end 
 //alter your array. As **Rayon Dabre** suggested wrap the elements
 //inside a div

 //clear div
 //correct this in your code it is written as .empty instead
 //of .empty()
 $("#results").empty();

 //iterate through array to display array values
 //same as above
 for (i = 0; i < ItemArray.length; i++) {

   var keysArray = Object.keys(ItemArray[i]);
   var valueToAppend = "";
   for (var m = 0; m < keysArray.length; m++) {
    valueToAppend += ItemArray[i][keysArray[m]] + " ";
   }

   $("#results").append(valueToAppend + " <br>")

   $("#results").append('<button class="Delete" value="' + i + '">Delete</button><br>'); //add delete button
 }
});
});
```

html

```
<form action="">
  First name:
  <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
  <br> Last name:
  <input id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse">
  <br> Address:
  <input id="Address" type="text" name="Address" value="Disneyland">
  <br>Country:
  <input id="Country" type="text" name="Country" value="USA">
  <br> Type:
  <input id="Type" type="text" name="Type" value="Cartoon-Character">
  <br>
</form>

<button>Submit</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

[See this working](https://jsfiddle.net/n2w3anzn/)